# Why does my laptop's screen remain black when I try to unlock it?

Tags: power-management, lock-screen, screensaver

After locking my laptop, every so often, when trying to unlock it, the screen remains black.

I see no cursor, and I can't switch to any of the other TTYs either.  I end up having to hard reset it. I'm running Lubuntu 16.04 64bit, on a Lenovo T460s laptop.

Comment: I think this solved the issue, but not sure yet:  https://www.reddit.com/r/thinkpad/comments/48n0fy/any_t460s_and_ubuntu_1604_beta1_success_stories/d0nej0n

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other screen savers like `xlock` or `xscreensaver`? I heard that the default `gnome-screensaver` has some issues on that, and that solved my issue in the past.

Comment: No I haven't; I'll take a look at that.

Comment: When I try to remove light-locker it wants to remove lubuntu-desktop.  Why?